# In Angular JS $scope variable value assign from $http

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to angular js. Here i have the code:  I receive the response data like number. In this code how i assign the response data as $scope.vote_counting. In this code does not return anything.

```
$scope.votes = function(){
        var votes = $http({
              method: "post",
              url: "/getVotes",
              data: { id: $scope.Id}
            }).success(function(response){  
            });
          return votes;
    }
```

Please anyone help to this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply call the `$http`. It does not have to be in a function

```
$http({
    method: "post",
    url: "/getVotes",
    data: { id: $scope.Id }
}).then(function(response) {
    //handle success
    $scope.votes_counting = response.data;
}, function(error){
    //handle error
});
```

The sort version is

```
$http.post("/getVotes", { id: $scope.Id }).then(function(response) {
    //handle success
    $scope.votes_counting = response.data;
}, function(error) {
    //handle error
})
```

*Note :* You are using a POST method but a GET method seems more appropriate in your case (`getVotes`)

Answer (score 1):

I've added a snippet, which shows the basic handling of promises. Here, I've used a service to mock a http call. The response is attached to a scope variable, which is presented in the view.

```js
angular.module('TestApp', [])
  .factory('MockHttp', function($q) {
    return {
      getMockData: function() {
        return $q.when(['A', 'B', 'C']);
      }
    };
  })
  .controller('TestController', function($scope, MockHttp) {
    $scope.res = null;

    MockHttp.getMockData()
      .then(function(res)  {
        $scope.res = res;
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        console.log(err);
      });

  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="TestApp">
  <div ng-controller="TestController">
    {{res}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The $http function does not return the response of the server. But as you have already figured out you can use the success function to get the servers response. Simply set `$scope.votes` value in the success function like this:

```
 $http({
   method: "post",
   url: "/getVotes",
   data: { id: $scope.Id}
 }).success(function(response){  
   $scope.votes = response
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is probably using [$http.post](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#post). Note that `success` is deprecated in favour of `then`:

```
$scope.retrieveVotes = function(){
  $http.post('/getVotes', {id : $scope.id}).then(function(response){  
    $scope.votes = response.data;
  });
}
```

Also note that `$http` calls are asynchronous so calling `retrieveVotes` is also asynchronous.

Comment: Why `$http.post()` ?

Comment: @Weedoze Because it's a shortcut for `$http({method: 'POST', ..)` making your code more readable and concise

Comment: Oh yeah, I didn't see that he was using a post... Even if the url is `getVotes`